# Angular buttons show and hide divs and change text on button.

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to make a button show and hide a div. I think I almost have it done, but I am missing this very last part.

Here is what I would like to happen: when you click on the red "change template" button, the text changes to "back to page 1". Now click on the red button again. The one that says "back to page 1" - I need that to actually change the div below to the yellow box. Right now it does nothing when you click on the red button the second time.

I would also need the text to change back to "change template". I am thinking what I need is a toggle button.

I have tried to implement multiple toggle buttons I found on stackoverflow already, but it seems my other code might be getting in the way. I made a plunker so its easy to see the problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RpqoXXHGBeYaBzIlD8Qb?p=preview

```
  <div class="btn top-menu-button finchbutton red" ng-click="finchange='show';finpage1='';finpage2='';finpage3='';hellotext='hide';goodbyetext='show'">
  <span class="btntext" ng-class="hellotext">Change Template</span><span class="btntext" ng-class="goodbyetext">Back To Template</span></div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton1 orange" ng-click="finpage1='show';finpage2='';finpage3='';finchange='';hellotext='show';goodbyetext='hide'">Page 1</div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton2 blue" ng-click="finpage2='show';finpage1='';finpage3='';finchange='';hellotext='show';goodbyetext='hide'">Page 2</div>
  <div class="btn top-menu-button finbutton3 pink" ng-click="finpage3='show';finpage1='';finpage2='';finchange='';hellotext='show';goodbyetext='hide'">Page 3</div>
```

---

UPDATE: Here is another one where the toggle button works. But when I try to add in the fade transitions (from the first plunker) and get the other buttons to work, it fails.

http://plnkr.co/edit/es5pgmrgsXbm6bP8CSrr?p=preview

I guess what I need to do is combine these two plunkers together, but I have been trying for a long time, since last night, and I can't seem to do it. I'm not even sure if it's possible.

If I use ng-hide and ng-show I lose the fade animation. So I don't think I want to use those.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood well what you expect for the color transitions:

```
code to plunker
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HDJkomatwYOrxTns1db4?p=preview

However, I didn't figured out what you want to do with hellotext and goodbyetext, but I'm pretty sure this shouldn't be a big issue for you now you have the solution to switch your panel

Comment: Sorry, I must not have explained it very well :( I wanted the first red button to toggle between the div changing form red to orange. Then the orange button to show the orange div. The blue button to show the blue div. and the pink button to show the pink div. In my original, it worked exactly how I wanted. Except that the red button didn't toggle between the red and orange div.